# Error: Unknown object type "asyncfunction"

Tags: serverless, aws-serverless

I have and issue with my serverless deployment to AWS. Im fairly new to it so I'm unsure as to what the issue is.

I have found a few solutions online but none have worked so any ideas would be greatly accepted. also I know there is a very similar question on here but that solution didnt work and after asking for more details nobody responded so I made a new question. Please help!

```
Error: Unknown object type "asyncfunction"
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:218:17)
          at Object._function (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:319:14)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at /Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
          at Object._function (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:319:14)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at /Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at /Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at /Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at /Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at /Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at /Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at /Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:246:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at Object._object (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:242:21)
          at Object.dispatch (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:185:30)
          at hash (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:128:10)
          at objectHash (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:33:10)
          at Function.exports.sha1 (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/object-hash/index.js:44:10)
          at AwsProvider.request (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/provider/awsProvider.js:234:35)
          at AwsDeploy.uploadZipFile (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/lib/uploadArtifacts.js:76:26)
          at BbPromise.map.concurrency (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/lib/uploadArtifacts.js:127:21)
          at tryCatcher (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
          at MappingPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/map.js:68:38)
          at MappingPromiseArray.PromiseArray._iterate (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:115:31)
          at MappingPromiseArray.init (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:79:10)
          at MappingPromiseArray._asyncInit (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/map.js:37:10)
          at _drainQueueStep (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:97:12)
          at _drainQueue (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
          at Async._drainQueues (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
          at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/mick/Desktop/service/api-user-service/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
          at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:463:21)
     
         For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
     
      Get Support --------------------------------------------
         Docs:          docs.serverless.com
         Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
         Issues:        forum.serverless.com
     
      Your Environment Information ---------------------------
         Operating System:          darwin
         Node Version:              15.6.0
         Framework Version:         1.63.0
         Plugin Version:            3.3.0
         SDK Version:               2.3.0
         Components Core Version:   1.1.2
         Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serverless - "Unknown object type asyncfunction" error during deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65276144/serverless-unknown-object-type-asyncfunction-error-during-deployment)

Answer (score 8):

The issue is happening with node version `v15.8.0`. Resolved by downgrading system version to `v14.15.5` using nvm

Comment: yup worked for me, took a lot of testing and a few other solutions as I have detailed in my answer but thank you!

Comment: Thank you, bro!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was 'object-hash' in Node modules

Remove the object hash references throughout the service (Use Find tool)

Had to comment out part of the code in the handlers

Remove the node modules folder altogether then

Then run yarn install to remove the object-hash dependency

Make sure it is uninstalled by using the find tool

Run `sls deploy` again

`Asynync Error` should be gone then....

If THEN run into a failed Uploaded file must be a non-empty zip

There is a problem with node version

Reduce to node version `14.15.1` here using homebrew (Mac)

Solved the issue for me!